# Is $localStorage.foo = foo (ngStorage) & localStorage['foo'] = foo the same?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage, ng-storage

```
foo = {test: ing}
```

Using ngStorage in an app and I am trying to update the value of

```
$localStorage.foo
```

with

```
localStorage['foo'] = bar
```

from outside of the application (in another file w/o angular, or through chrome console)

I am storing the obj, and when I try to console log it, it's returning [object Object].. I was wondering if it is possible to set the ngStorage value, from a non angular application/ chrome console with bracket notation? Sorry if it's unclear, I'm really confused myself.

Comment: Are you asking about the difference between `$localStorage` and `localStorage`, or the difference between `baz.foo` and `baz['foo']`?

Comment: $localStorage.foo = bar, and localStorage['foo'] = bar

wondering if they access the exact same thing

Comment: So... both? It's a bit unclear what the actual problem is. There is no difference between `.foo` and `['foo']`.

Comment: Actually it sounds more like they are asking about changing localStorage outside of an angular app (i.e. in another page/tab/window etc), and have it updated inside the angular app's ngStorage ($localStorage) module

Comment: Sorry, I meant exactly what Patrick Evans said.

Comment: It's saving to the right key now, however saving as [object Object] ..